# Read data from file and convert to key value pair

Tags: java, arrays

I have the below integers in File :

758 29

206 58

122 89

I have to read these integers in an integer array and then need to store the values in key value pair. Then print the output as :

Position 29 has been initialized to value 758.

Position 89 has been initialized to value 122.

I have tried as of now :

```
private static Scanner readFile() {
        /*
         * Your program will prompt for the name of an input file and the read
         * and process the data contained in this file. You will use three
         * integer arrays, data[], forward[] and backward[] each containing 100
         * elements
         */
        int data[] = new int[100];
        int forward[] = new int[100];
        int backward[] = new int[100];



        System.out.print("Please enter File Name : ");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = scanner.nextLine();
        File inputFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner linReader = null;
        try {
            linReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while (linReader.hasNext()) {
                String intStringSplit = linReader.nextLine();
                String[] line = intStringSplit.split("\t",-1);
                data = new int[line.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            linReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }

        return linReader;
    }
```

I am not able to figure out how to get the key and value from the read data.

Comment: Which column represents the key and which the value?  You seem to be using them interchangeably.  Also, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen Sorry my mistake , column 2nd is the key here and Column 1st is value. I am able to read data from file , store it in array. I am not able to differentiate between key and value here.

Comment: You need to post the code you already wrote for doing this and explain which exact part is not working correctly so we can help answer whatever specific question you have.

Comment: Hi @csm_dev Code posted done till date. How Do i separate the key value pair.

Comment: Use split like you have done, but do it on a character that is existing in the string which I think `\t` is not. Like `intStringSplit.split(" ")` instead of `intStringSplit.split("\t",-1)`;.

Comment: I tried intStringSplit.split(" ") but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

When posting information related to your question it is very important that you provide the data (in file for example) exactly as it is intended in reality so that we can make a more positive determination as to why you are experiencing difficulty with your code.

What you show as an in file data example indicates that each file line (which contains actual data) consists of two specific integer values. The first value being the **initialization** value and the second being the **position** value.

There also appears to be a blank line after ever line which contains actual data. This really doesn't matter since the code provided below has a code line to take care of such a thing but it could be the reason as to why you may be having difficulty.

To me, it looks like the delimiter used to separate the two integer values in each file line is indeed a **whitespace** as @csm_dev has already mentioned within his/her comment but you claim you tried this in your **String.split()** method and determined it is not a whitespace. If this is truly the case then it will be up to you to determine exactly what that delimiter might be. We couldn't possibly tell you since we don't have access to the real file.

You declare a File object within your provided code but yet nowhere do you utilize it. You may as well delete it since all it's doing is sucking up oxygen as far as I'm concerned.

When using **try/catch** it's always good practice to catch the proper exceptions which in this case is: **IOException**. It doesn't hurt to also display the stack trace as well upon an exception since it can solve a lot of your coding problems should an exception occur.

This code should work:

```
private static Scanner readFile() {
    /*
     * Your program will prompt for the name of an input file and the read
     * and process the data contained in this file. You will use three
     * integer arrays, data[], forward[] and backward[] each containing 100
     * elements
     */
    int data[] = new int[100];
    int forward[] = new int[100];
    int backward[] = new int[100];

    System.out.print("Please enter File Name : ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filename = scanner.nextLine();
    File inputFile = new File(filename); // why do you have this. It's doing nothing.
    Scanner linReader = null;
    try {
        linReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (linReader.hasNext()) {
            String intStringSplit = linReader.nextLine();
            // If the file line is blank then just 
            // continue to the next file line.
            if (intStringSplit.trim().equals("")) { continue; }

            // Assuming at least one whitespace is used as 
            // the data delimiter but what the heck, we'll
            // use a regular expression within the split() 
            // method to handle any number of spaces between
            // the integer values.
            String[] line = intStringSplit.split("\\s+"); 
            data = new int[line.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                data[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("Position " + data[1] + 
                    " has been initialized to value " + 
                    data[0] + ".");
            // do whatever else you need to do with the 
            // data array before reading in the next file
            // line......................................
        }
        linReader.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return linReader;
}
```